# How can I make the Django contrib Admin change list for a particular model class editable with drop downs for related items displayed in the listing?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-templates, django-forms

Basically I want to have an editable form for related entries instead of a static listing.

Answer (score 1):

Try Django 1.1 beta. It's got the option to make items in the changelist editable (as well as incorporating the django-batchadmin project)